# Magento 2 "Payment capturing error" on checkout page

Tags: magento2, payment

I'm using magento 2.0.7 with php 5.6 , and I've installed Inchoo Stripe payment gateway, and also Stripe library. Got it working backend and frontend , but when I go on checkout page , I insert the CC info , an try to pay , I get this error :

`Payment capturing error`

Answer (score 0):

Check you're stripe dashboard for errors. If you're in test mode but you're using a real credit card it will decline and you will get that error on magento2.

https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm

Follow that link and use one of the test credit card numbers and see what happens with magento2 and stripe.